# stop ant build if makefile fails

Tags: ant, java-native-interface, makefile

I have an ant build file that executes a makefile

```
        <target name="jni">
            <exec executable="make">
                <arg line="-f jni/Makefile"/>
            </exec>
        </target>
```

however if the make fails the other rules that depend on this rule will execute

how can I stop ant if the jni rule fails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the `failonerror` attribute, which is `false` by default:

```
<target name="jni">
    <exec executable="make" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="-f jni/Makefile"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

I never stop wondering why it is not true by default...
[See the docs.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

Comment: YEAH! its almost like they expect me to RTFM !!